# Privileges on catalog tables are not revoked

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

Using `Redshift` and unable to revoke all privileges on `pg_catalog` schema from `myuser`

```
dev=# REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA pg_catalog FROM myuser;
REVOKE
dev=# SELECT
    u.usename,
    s.schemaname,
    has_schema_privilege(u.usename,s.schemaname,'create') AS user_has_select_permission,
    has_schema_privilege(u.usename,s.schemaname,'usage') AS user_has_usage_permission
FROM
    pg_user u
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT schemaname FROM pg_tables) s
WHERE
    u.usename = 'myuser'
    AND s.schemaname = 'pg_catalog'
;
 usename | schemaname | user_has_select_permission | user_has_usage_permission
---------+------------+----------------------------+---------------------------
 myuser  | pg_catalog | f                          | t
(1 row)
```

why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because those privilege are granted to `PUBLIC` that is, everyone.

Also, privileges in SQL are cumulative: you cannot add “negative privileges”, that is, make an exception. In other words, you can only revoke a privilege that was previously granted. Moreover, the attempt to `REVOKE` a privilege that was never granted is neither an error nor does it produce a warning, but it is silently ignored.

Now since the privileges on the catalog tables are granted to `PUBLIC`, not to `myuser`, your `REVOKE` does nothing.

Again I warn you: don't attempt to revoke privileges on the catalog tables!

Comment: When you say "those privileges are granted to `PUBLIC`", you mean `PUBLIC` group? I am asking because when I do `SELECT * from pg_groups` it returns 0 rows

Comment: Right; it is a "pseudo-group". For example, you cannot drop it. It is hard-wired into the system.